# Match patternA and print it only when patternB is matched including the following line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am looking to get all the lines which have the word 'search_string' + the line after it + the line matching 'mod' before it.
I tried:

```
grep -n 'mod\|search_string' ip | grep --before 1 search_string> inter  
grep -n --after 1 search_string ip >> inter  
sort -t':' -k1,1n -u inter -o op
```

Is there a better way?

File:

```
mod start1  
some lines  
mod start2  
other lines  
mod start3  
 many other lines  
 search_string yada yada  
 hello  
 many other lines  
 search_string yada yada  
 bye  
mod start4  
 search_string baba baba  
 this too  
mod start5
```

Expected output :

```
mod start3  
 search_string yada yada   
 hello  
 search_string yada yada  
 bye  
mod start4  
 search_string baba baba  
 this too
```

Comment: In your example you have `search_string` and `search string`. Are they both valid?

Comment: The output of the commands you show do not match the expected output you present. Which is correct ?

Comment: It was a typo. Corrected it to show search_string. The final results should match the expected results. I was only trying to show the convoluted steps I was thinking of and not getting proper results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
   $0 ~ /mod/ { md=$0 }
   $0 ~ /search_string/ { if(md!="") { print md }; md="" ; print; getline; print }
   '
```

Explanation:

- A line containing `mod` is saved as `md`.
- A line containing `search_string` triggers printing the previously saved `md`, the line itself and the next line.
- `if(md!="")` and `md=""` are there to make sure you don't get duplicated `mod` lines when there are many `search_string`-s under a single `mod` (`mod start3` in your example).

Note:

- A line containing both `mod` and `search_string` will break this logic.

Comment: Kamil, Thankyou! This works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your file contains "carriage return" characters. It is better to remove them in Unix. To print what the sequence of commands you posted print (with carriage returns removed), try:

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")}
     /mod/          { a = $0 }
     /search_string/{ if(a!=""){print(a);a=""}
                      print;getline;print
                    }
    ' infile
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")}/mod/{a=$0}/search_string/{if(a!=""){print(a);a=""}print;getline;print}' infile

mod start3  
 search_string yada yada  
 hello  
 search_string yada yada  
 bye  
mod start4  
 search_string baba baba  
 this too
```

---

As it is possible to use a multi character record separator in (GNU) awk we can set the record separator to `mod` and print only records that contain `search_string`. The printf is required to reconstruct the original record.

To print what you posted as "Expected output" try:

```
awk '/search_string/{printf("mod%s", $0)}' RS=mod infile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this in a Python script:

```
# Read file into memory.
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

# Loops through lines backwards, looking for string and optionally mod.
output_lines = list()
find_mod = False
for i, line in enumerate(lines[::-1]):
    if 'search_string' in line:
        output_lines.append(lines[::-1][i-1])
        output_lines.append(lines[::-1][i])
        find_mod = True
    elif find_mod and 'mod' in line:
        output_lines.append(lines[::-1][i])
        find_mod=False

print("\n".join(output_lines[::-1]))
```